# check git revision is ahead of origin/master without a clone?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, git-clone

I have a CI/CD system set up and I am trying to make sure that before anything gets released that a specific commit which was stored against the release is currently ahead of master.

Currently the only way I can find to do this is:

```
git clone -q https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$GITREPOSITORYURL s
cd s
git checkout -q $revisionhash 
git merge origin/master | grep "Already up-to-date." || (>&2 echo "You are behind master");
```

the problem is that this takes ages...

Is there a better way in which I can do this without having to clone?

I should also mention that the builds are happening on cloud servers and are spun up and torn down after every release. so we can't persist the repo.

Comment: `git branch --contains $revisionhash | grep master` ?

Comment: would still have the clone in that instance which is the slow bit...

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think the wire protocol allows for this kind of query.

Comment: is there not something I can do like git clone --depth 1 master $revision? to only get those two branches?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the server you use to host your remote provides some advanced query capability (e.g. through a webapi), you're going to need a local repo.  That doesn't necessarily mean a full clone, but you still have only limited ability to express to git what you want it to copy.  Also, even if you do ask for a limited history, I'm not sure whether the server implementation is obligated to minimize the network traffic, or whether a "clever" server might try to send you an existing pack that contains everything you asked for (and maybe more).

So one place you can start, if you're sure that `release` contains at least one commit not in `master`, would be

```
git clone --bare -b release --single-branch --shallow-exclude master -q https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$GITREPOSITORYURL s
```

Note I've used `--bare` to suppress the default checkout, because you shouldn't need it for this and that could save a little time.  Now the idea here is, as a starting point, to fetch only the commits that are in the release branch but *not* in `master`.

"But wait", you say, "why not the other way around?"  After all, you're trying to determine specifically whether "commits in master but not in release" is an empty set; so just fetch that, right?  The problem is, if the ref in the `-b` argument is reachable from the ref in the `--shallow-exclude` argument, you end up pulling the full history - which is what we're trying to avoid.  (The exact reasoning is probably just that the positive ref overrides the negative ref, but the upshot is that if the exclusion would leave you an empty set, you get a full history instead.)  That's why you'd want to know for sure that `release` has at least one commit unreachable from `master`.

(I toyed with a couple ways of trying to add a "backstop", so that at most a limited history is fetched; I was not able to make it work, though I suspect that could reflect a bug in how exclusions are calculated.  Or maybe that's a matter of interpretation.  Regardless...)

Well, if you've successfully fetched the release branch, then the next thing you need is to find its first commit.  It's debatable whether this should work, but it seems to in my tests:

```
git log --max-parents=0 --format="%H"
```

I say it's debatable if this should work because the first commit in your clone isn't *really* a root commit.  The commit object still hast to list its parent ID (as we'll see in a moment), and yet for certain commands git apparently "doesn't count" this parent (presumably because it's not in the local repo), and I guess we can capitalize on that here.

Now what you really want is to see the first commit's parent ID, and this is where git commands ignoring the parent is a double-edged sword.  Because

```
git log --format="%P" <first-commit>
```

won't work; it acts as though there were no parent.  So instead we can

```
 git cat-file -p $(git log --max-parents=0 --format="%H") |grep '^parent' |cut -c8-
```

to read the parent hash from the `COMMIT` object itself.

Now we know that the ID we just extracted is the ID of the first commit reachable from `release` that's *also* reachable from `master` (because "reachable from `master`" is the only reason the commit would've been excluded from our clone).  We can also say that of the commits reachable from `master`, it's the *last* one reachable from `release`.

So our question is: is that commit ID equal to the `master` ref.

And we can answer that with

```
git ls-remote https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$GITREPOSITORYURL |grep refs/heads/master$ |cut -c-40
```